# Error of a function containing complex numbers

Tags: error-propagation

Please, what is  **the statistical error formula of the function f (uncertainty)** by Mathematica code:

```
a=x+I y ; b=u+I v;    
f=Abs[a]^2+Abs[b]^2;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$Version

(* "12.0.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (April 7, 2019)" *)

a = Around[x, dx] + I Around[y, dy]
```

[image]

```
b = Around[u, du] + I Around[v, dv]
```

[image]

```
f = Abs[a]^2 + Abs[b]^2
```

[image]

```
f // FullSimplify[#, Element[{x, dx, y, dy, u, du, v, dv}, Reals]] &
```

[image]